# AngularJS : Scope variable not updating fast enough

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have the following code in my directive.

```
//Directive Code
var BooleanWidgetController = function ($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.booleanOptions = [
        {
            displayText: '-- ' + $filter('i18n')('Widgets.Generics.Select') + ' --'
        },
        {
            value: 1,
            displayText: $filter('i18n')('Widgets.Generics.Yes')
        },
        {
            value: 0,
            displayText: $filter('i18n')('Widgets.Generics.No')
        }
    ];

    //Added inside watch because query was not being updated if filterUpdated was called using ng-change
    $scope.$watch('query', $scope.filterUpdated);
};

app.directive('acxBooleanColumnHeaderFilter', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        replace: true,
        controller: ['$scope', '$filter', BooleanWidgetController],
        scope: {
            query: '=',
            filterUpdated: '&submit',
            columnHeading: '@'
        },
        templateUrl: 'mailSearch/directives/columnHeaderWidgets/boolean/booleanColumnHeaderWidget.tpl.html'
    };
});

//Template
<div class="columnHeaderWidget">
<div class="title pull-left">{{columnHeading}}</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<select ng-model="query" ng-options="option.value as option.displayText for option in booleanOptions">
</select>
```

The current way is working fine. But when I try to do something like this.

```
<select ng-model="query" ng-change="filterUpdated" ng-options="option.value as option.displayText for option in booleanOptions">
```

The $scope.query is not updating fast enough. So the $scope.query is being updated after $scope.filterUpdated is being called. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This is far more complicated than what it seems, if you want to understand the real problem have a look at this: "[Explaining the order of the ngModel pipeline, parsers, formatters, viewChangeListeners, and $watchers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778149/directives-isolated-scopes-bound-properties-and-ng-click)".

To summarize, the issue is that: when the `ng-change` function gets triggered the bound scope properties of your directive (in your case `query`) have been updated in the scope of the directive, but not in the scope from where they were inherited from.

The workaround that I would suggest would be:

- Change your `filterUpdated` function so that it will take the `query` from a parameter, rather than taking it from its `scope`, because its `scope` hasn't been updated yet.
- Create an intermediate function in the `scope` of your directive in order to catch the `ng-change` event and the updated scope properties.
- Use that intermediate function to call the `filterUpdated` function and pass the `query` as a parameter.

Something like this:

```
var BooleanWidgetController = function ($scope, $filter) {

    $scope.booleanOptions = [
        {
            displayText: '-- ' + $filter('i18n')('Widgets.Generics.Select') + ' --'
        },
        {
            value: 1,
            displayText: $filter('i18n')('Widgets.Generics.Yes')
        },
        {
            value: 0,
            displayText: $filter('i18n')('Widgets.Generics.No')
        }
    ];

    $scope._filterUpdated = function(){ $scope.filterUpdated({query:$scope.query}); };        

    /** Remove this, you won't need it anymore
     ** $scope.$watch('query', $scope.filterUpdated);
     **/
};
```

Change your HTML, make it look like this:

```
<select ng-model="query" ng-change="_filterUpdated" ng-options="option.value as option.displayText for option in booleanOptions">
```

And remember to change the `filterUpdated` to use the query as a parameter, like this:

```
function filterUpdated(query){
   ...
}
```

Comment: My code is already working as mentioned in the question, But what I am not able to understand is why the query scope variable not updating fast enough. If I do a cascaded call like $scope.query = 0; $scope.filterUpdated();, the filterUpdated function will not have the $scope.query as 0 rather $scope.query will have previous value.